# Fully understanding a universe from within that universe. Gödel's second theorem

Tags: physics, mathematics, philosophy

Gödel's second theorem asserts that the consistency of a formal theory containing arithmetic cannot be proved by the tools of the relevant theory itself (provided that the theory is in fact consistent).

Because we are inside and bound by the tools of our universe, this seems to imply that either we can never develop a formal arithmetical theory that fully explains the workings of our universe or that our universe is inconsistent.

Is my logic correct?

> **Gödel's incompleteness theorems**
>
> https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Consistency

Comment: Maybe this should be adked in Math.SE

Comment: But there is a *Mathematics* tag for this SE so I thought it would be appropriate.

Comment: The [tag:mathematics} states that it is for question about mathematics "focusing on their effects on societies and civilizations." The question as stated is asking for an existential proof of our real, existing universe. The two are not related.

Comment: @Frostfyre - Philosophy and science have an important impact on society even if the population at large aren't concerned with those subjects. If the universe were found to be inconsistent then headlines from news hungry journalists would probably proclaim, "Proof of God's existence. We aren't totally ruled by science!". A question cannot cover everything. If I'd asked about the implications for society the question would have been closed as too broad.

Comment: But your question isn't asking about the impacts of mathematics on society, and that is what the tag is for. This question is asking for clarification about an existing theory. That's not worldbuilding.

Comment: I'm sorry but questions like "What is the impact on society of X" are routinely closed because they are considered 'too broad' or 'a matter of opinion'. This seems like a Catch 22.

Comment: I've got to agree, this seems more like a philosophical discussion than a worldbuilding question. Mike Scott does hit the nail on his head with the answer, and you can see that this answer has little to do with worldbuilding.

Comment: This is interesting philosophy question , but not worldbuilding one. You may be interested in https://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect, because our universe is not a formal system of logic, and so the Incompleteness Theorem does not apply to it. Furthermore, the Incompleteness Theorem requires an infinite domain, but the observable universe is finite, so there are only a finite number of statements you can make about it. A system which admits only a finite number of statements can be consistent and provable.

Comment: So the latter half of your reply implies that there is a 'bottom' to the granularity of the universe. The overall size of the universe may be finite but the depth we could go in discovering ever smaller and smaller fundamental 'particles' is at least conceivably infinite.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Unbounded is not the same thing as infinite. There may be no lower bound on the size of the smallest particle we can observe, and thus no upper bound on the number of particles in the universe, but that doesn't mean that it can be infinite. Think of the biggest whole number you can -- it's unbounded, and can be as high as you can imagine, but it can't be infinite.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK why is it conceivable for there to be an infinite number of smaller particles? You shouldn't think about it from a human perspective, looking at a large atom and finding out it's made up of smaller and smaller elements. You should think about it from a logical perspective, which is to start at the beginning. If it's infinite, there is no beginning, and your building blocks all depend on a smaller element without there ever being a fundamental, smallest one. Now whether or not we will ever be able to observe that is another story.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK No. The latter half of the answer doesn't imply granularity 'bottoms out". Instead it states a finite universe can be described consistently and provably by a finite number of statements.